# Using the standard Android Gallery as the basis for my own app

Tags: android, gallery, mediastore

I am trying to do something that should be easy enough but I am in really bad shape because I can't find any single valid answer for this.

Is there a way to get (or build) the basic Gallery you find in all Android devices. Something simple that scans for all pictures in the SD card and shows them in the screen sliding left and right...

The only thing I have found is HelloGallery; completely useless Google code that will use an adapter based on r.drawable.xxx files...

Is there nothing out there that does the same but based on a MediaStore based URI?

Thanks and sorry if this is a really dumb question.

Comment: Not sure if what you're looking for is sample code or advice for writing a new view. Have you familiarized yourself with the basics of androids UI?

Comment: wow....completely useless Google code. You are the man to challenge google code :D

Answer (score 0):

This simplifies to to scan images from sdcard,get all images uri.You have to create gallery class and its adapter class.if you want to sliding left and right ,in adapter class take one layout with both are fill parent,and put a image in center of that layout Or give images to fill parent.I am commented below case also working,check it also..

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllImagesUri(ContentResolver mResolver) {
        ArrayList<String> imagesUris = new ArrayList<String>();
        try{

//      Cursor mCursor = mResolver.query(
//              MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
//              new String[] { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,MediaStore.Images.Media._ID }, null, null,
//              null);
        Cursor mCursor = mResolver.query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA ,MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID }, null, null,
                null);


        startManagingCursor(mCursor);

        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                try {
                    imagesUris.add(mCursor.getString(0));
                    imagesIds.add(mCursor.getString(1));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
        }

        }catch (Exception e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        return imagesUris;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I finally used either the 3D Gallery which cooliris built and cyanogen put toghether in GIT or its previous version for older devices. It needed a good amount of work to make it run but it is good code to get a comprehensive understantingd of this topic.